# A good way to pack GPIO_pin and GPIO_port in STM32

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32

In my STM32 **C++** project, I want to define a struct (or class or macro) to pack the port and pin information

```
LED_PIN = Something{GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5}
```

So, I can write something like this

```
while(true){
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_PIN.port, LED_PIN.pin); //or using member method or anything similar
  HAL_Delay(500);
}
```

Here, I want **LED_PIN.pin** and **LED_PIN.port** to be const during compilation so that they can be used as case labels and it also will save space.

It is worth noting that **GPIO_A** is defined as **((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)** in the HAL header, so it cannot directly be used to initialize a constexpr due to that reinterpret_cast.

Comment: What do you mean case labels? Case labels can only be integers - the port needs to be a (volatile-qualified) pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```cpp
struct IOPin
{
    GPIO_TypeDef *port;
    uint16_t pin;
};

constexpr IOPin PA0{GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0};
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzACspAAOqAqETgwe3r4BaRlZAqHhUSyx8cm2mPaOAkIETMQEuT5%2BXIF2mA7Zjc0EpZExcYkpCk0tbfmdtpODYcMVo8kAlLaoXsTI7BzmCWHI3lgA1CYJbsgT%2BILn2CYaAIIPz2YJWDThJ9/fAPq/AEkAPI/E4AN08TEc9BeLwIAE9UpgPicJsQvA5YQB2KxPP6AkFeMIEBJmX4EE4AWSBABFsAAlc4WUEAegAVGAwOc3CcAOLKYEndItE4sDCYE7ETDAPATOKkUGKpWPdDoKUKBQnVBUKhKAggE4aVQaDRKtksl74wVEwSk8knIEAFQAmsoGUyfuzOdy%2BQKQcKKZsCKkvBSEUjJdLZQR5Urviq1ZgNVqdXqDUaNJIzRa8Sd/tbiXaKUChG7sDTGQlmScvVyLr7BQGtaGQxSFEjkZGZXKyHGE%2BrNdrdZh9YbjQAObOWvMEk42klkinKOTKCsez0cus8/mNkgUkO0WgAWi8qRZB%2BP6FQAHcGF3o7GTv2k4PUyP08aeYrzdP84TC4uJwAmuVZKrWPo7v6e4nGErYnOgUJMPePYKnGT6qgOKbDqORpcKa345o8Vr/ragG0pW1aspuEF%2BkK0FBnBCFNMhMa9n2GEvlhaZjlIU65n%2Bc4AfaFhCPSFGKuB9aQXRIrRIQqIjiy6ojixj6gs%2ByZDtxuGTgRv6zvORYnMEbgANLiVR3pSbRTZoAwNDAFsULZCctCoMgADWqm9hpr7YR%2BXBfqCP78QZQkUo8ABijJJBYZgmEkNLrjW1HWYKYiscwMYnFQXgML0AjeQoqE/L5XHvmOZgaEeRpmFmIXPFiNINkCvyOoimA0pgVBMrCTz7B8iwnG69IAsoAASvwWI8QjYGhPxGpIJrLSacjBLCbyDV8jzjRYXAjWNk3TbNcYQAdE1TTNc3WGOy1Vcta2rBt7zdUNkGPJdJ3zd8EA7Xt51HVdZyWLdD3BE9/Wba9Xzvd9p0QJBbUdV1VAnGyqwtR9x3YBDzyQy9nwSojAoRL8%2BHfVA86dOSqwZiaXC4y8LLMyzrNs%2BzHOc1z3M87zfMc0zLJw8LItxnIcQnB4pyizLIvM4L/OK0rysq0rfWPGiGIUsCyhhNiuJET8iPtUiKNowGvW5t8VP%2BPaqR61W2JJY7/VPHZcqqKkxBAUCut3sojwaCYOLvQqxMAqTQdNZbeOPMSopMGEECMzi07fAHGgAHQBkedwiWJZwJM1GfZw7BvBzSHDrLQnBJLwfgcFopCoJwbjWDdCibNsEr7DwpD6o3VfrB5IBJBo%2BicJI9eaLwLccLwCggOPA9aOscCwDAiAoKgLD2/QZAUBAaC73QozNCweFmFwfB0Kxi8QNEM%2BkHJzDEPCnB98fbCCECDC0O/g9SBYBYIYYA4hAH4ClL0MESYn6YFUD0UMuw%2B7ElqE/WgeBojEGaPCKWyDeAEGIHgFgH8q58AMMABQAA1PAmBrxAiRA3Pu/BBAiDEOwKQMhBCKBUOoQBuhr4GCMCgdulh9CYMXpAdYqBUj1AYIvDgR5rjnBpKYSw1gqonCPECBIWiWDIBDCotALR4FHhYFmMxBAEAxD0VQNyUIjxMDkiohAzR0C2MMUXKgqQwSSCUakI86BOhaKoAwVAR54E7FkdkBQC9ag9DkS4Bg7hPDtD0CERY5RKh6HSJkOR0wOiFDydkIYWTRjX26AVBg/QpipJmDUOofR5ilJGPECp8wCl6AmAMFpyw2nrE7lsHYehCGYHwdXWu09AFz0ePSSkJxgDIGQCcPCmczCZy4CcCAYTwgYwgG3dRYiTi4EICQYGCRr6Sx3nvCWvdVgEJnqsYeo9x41w4FPUgJCx6kAbk3OeC8l790eaQdeW8GKhnIJQY%2BNy2lBHwEQWFLDhCiHEJwpFPC1BP1Gfg0g15sGpFIRMjgdcflPznkCFsoYUxPjmQspZKys7rM2dsgQmA9keBPvvc5DMHmDyeaQBAmAmBYHiMnCe7zeBfPHr82enAAXL0ec875byEhTL%2BXKoFfKiVmDVbK%2BemrV7rBgcQTIzhJBAA)

Comment: Assuming the `IO` qualifier expands to `volatile`, then only the `port` member should have been `volatile`. Making `pin` volatile too may or may not affect code generation in ways that at least I cannot easily foresee. Suppose we wish to do some manner of arithmetic with the pin member, for example.

Comment: @Lundin in the code above, `IO` is just a name of the struct, not a qualifier. I guess the name could be changed to something a bit more descriptive. As you expect, the port is volatile qualified in the declaration of `GPIO_TypeDef`.

Comment: Many bloat libs use `I`, `O` and `IO` specifically for expanding to `volatile`. I might be mixing up ST and Microchip bloat libs though.

Comment: I updated the name to IOPin, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works? `reinterpret_cast` is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen hundreds of attempts to abstract away simple GPIO and written a fair amount of such attempts myself. It never ends well, we always end up with something which is unintuitive or bloated or hard to read for other programmers.

Bluntly, the clearest and most readable way is simply this:

```
#define LED_PORT GPIOA 
#define LED_PIN  GPIO_PIN_5

LED_PORT |= LED_PIN;  // set pin
LED_PORT &= ~LED_PIN; // clear pin
LED_PORT ^= LED_PIN;  // toggle pin
```

This is as fast, readable and portable as it gets - it cannot be improved further.
This code is easily understood by 100% of all C and C++ programmers and compiles portably on 100% of all tool chains. It does not lead to questionable pointer conversions or potential overhead.

Yes you can write a GPIO HAL in case there are more non-trivial things it needs to handle, such as interrupts or port routing. But just for plain bit-banging I/O, there is no reason to invent some HAL.

Comment: To be fair, even your method will not be as simple, a more realistic code would be `LED_PORT->BSRR |= LED_PIN`. And how about initialization? Personally, I prefer to be able to intialize a GPIO with a single line of code. The other benefit of abstracting a GPIO is ability to hide the hardware implementation details, such as whether the signal is supposed to be active low or active high.