# Use of Generics for Embedded HAL Structs

Tags: rust, embedded, hal

I am writing an embedded program for an STM32 microcontroller. I would like to be able to store the GPIO pins that represent buttons in a nice, consolidated struct.

Because embedded-hal encodes the state of a "Pin" struct with generics, each GPIO has a different Rust type, however for my case (buttons) they all implement the embedded_hal::digital::v2::InputPin trait.

I could explicitly specify the type for each member, however I also have to write the pin and port for each button when doing configuration, i.e.:

```
    let mut middle = gpioa
        .pa6
        .into_pull_up_input(&mut gpioa.moder, &mut gpioa.pupdr);
```

This means that specifying the type in the struct would cause redundancy, and if ever I need to change a pin in hardware, I will need to change it in code in more than one place.

What is the canonical way to store these pins? Of course I cannot use trait objects as it is in an embedded context.

At the moment I have the following:

```
use embedded_hal::digital::v2::InputPin;

struct Buttons<M, R, L, U, D>
where
    M: InputPin,
    R: InputPin,
    L: InputPin,
    U: InputPin,
    D: InputPin,
{
    middle: M,
    right: R,
    left: L,
    up: U,
    down: D
}
```

However this seems like a potential code smell.

Also, if I want to store this button struct inside another struct, the number of generics will most likely be very big in this parent struct unless I explicitly specify (and therefore write twice) the pin type.

Is there a better way to do this which is also efficient?

Comment: This would be a duplicate [A good way to pack GPIO_pin and GPIO_port in STM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375612/a-good-way-to-pack-gpio-pin-and-gpio-port-in-stm32) but I just realised you are using Rust...

Answer (score 4):

You can encapsulate the 5 types within a single one using associated types as such:

```rust
trait InputPin {}

trait InputPins {
    type M: InputPin;
    type R: InputPin;
    type L: InputPin;
    type U: InputPin;
    type D: InputPin;
}

struct Buttons<Pins: InputPins> {
    middle: Pins::M,
    right: Pins::R,
    left: Pins::L,
    up: Pins::U,
    down: Pins::D
}
```

Then to instantiate the `Buttons` you would use a single type that implements all of your necessary types using the `InputPins` trait.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely the most succinct method so far without any unnecessary check/overhead. However, I still have the issue that the types have to be repeated, since the function calls to setup the pins also refer to the types. I guess I will just hardcode them for now

Answer (score 1):

Given some structs that all implement `InputPin`,

```rust
struct M;
struct R;
struct L;
struct U;
struct D;
```

you can construct an enum that also implements `InputPin`:

```rust
enum Pin {
    M(M),
    R(R),
    L(L),
    U(U),
    D(D),
}

impl InputPin for Pin {
    type Error = ...;

    fn is_high(&self) -> Result<bool, Self::Error> {
        match self {
            Pin::M(pin) => pin.is_high(),
            Pin::R(pin) => pin.is_high(),
            Pin::L(pin) => pin.is_high(),
            Pin::U(pin) => pin.is_high(),
            Pin::D(pin) => pin.is_high(),
        }
    }

    fn is_low(&self) -> Result<bool, Self::Error> {
        match self {
            Pin::M(pin) => pin.is_low(),
            Pin::R(pin) => pin.is_low(),
            Pin::L(pin) => pin.is_low(),
            Pin::U(pin) => pin.is_low(),
            Pin::D(pin) => pin.is_low(),
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use the `Pin` enum everywhere without generics.

As this can become cumbersome and repetitive, there is a handy crate to do it for you: [enum_dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch). It even claims to result in better performance than the handwritten code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`into_dynamic`](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f4xx-hal/blob/cf1eace18f47af1026dc52fa0ff70fa968a22dbf/src/gpio/convert.rs#L202). It removes some type information, namely the pin, but still has the port in the type.

[`atsamd-hal`](https://github.com/atsamd-rs/atsamd) has [`DynPin`](https://github.com/atsamd-rs/atsamd/blob/afa4749793e20dd054312b769784b9d2953eb0dd/hal/src/gpio/dynpin.rs#L1..L7), which does fully remove all type information. Something like this is what you need, but I'm not as familiar with the ST HALs.